# How to do complex pattern matching of enums mixed with structs

Tags: rust

Currently, given an `A`, if I want to return `true` if it contains a `D` with true, I have to do the following:

```
pub enum A{
    B(B),
    C(C)
}

pub struct B{
    b1: D,
    b2: bool
}


pub struct C{}

pub struct D{
    d1: E
}

pub struct E{
    e1: bool
}

fn main() {
    let something = A::B(B{b1: D{d1: E{e1: true}}, b2: false});
    let e1_result = if let A::B(B{b1, b2}) = something {
        if let D{d1} = b1 {
            if let E{e1} = d1 {
                e1
            } else {
                false
            }
        } else {
            false
        }
    } else {
        false
    };
}
```

Is there a clean way to match over `d_1`? What if some time is boxed? Example: `pub struct D{ d_1: Box<E>}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can nest patterns:

```rust
let e1_result = if let A::B(B {
    b1: D { d1: E { e1: true } },
    ..
}) = something
{
    true
} else {
    false
};
```

At this point you can just use [`matches!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.matches.html):

```rust
let e1_result = matches!(something, A::B(B { b1: D { d1: E { e1: true } }, .. }));
```

However, if you have `Box` in the middle, you're out of luck. You can use the unstable feature [`box_patterns`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/box-patterns.html), though I won't recommend to: it is unlikely to be stabilized (rather some form of [deref patterns](https://github.com/rust-lang/lang-team/issues/88), but this has not yet been implemented). Yoy have to separate the patterns.

As a side note, when you have an [irrefutable pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#refutability) (a pattern that cannot fail) such as `D` and `E` in your code, you can use just `let`, no need for `if let`. Also, you can ignore unused fields with `..` or `_`.